# Is there a way to escape the hash (#) symbol in a URL without using the URL escape code (%23)

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing a url that can have a fragment identifier. I need to have this download as a file with ll its content. I can't use PHP or anything other than JavaScript.

`var myString = "Check out http://example.com#subtopic"`

It is downloaded by adding `"data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"` to it, setting it as the href attribute of a link  element and clicking on it.

`<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,Check out http://example.com#subtopic">`

The issue I have is that the formatted string (above) ends up being downloaded with just the following content:

`Check out http://example.com`

Because everything following the hash symbol is being treated as a fragment identifier. As mentioned, I can't replace the hash symbol with the URL escape character (%23) because then it would be downloaded as 
`"Check out http://example.com%23subtopic"` which is incorrect. Is there some other way of downloading the text file?

Comment: I've just tested it. %23 gets converted to # in the downloaded CSV file.

Comment: "*I can't replace the hash symbol with the URL escape character (%23)*" - yes you can. URL encoding works just fine in data urls. What browser/tool do you use to open/download it?

Comment: Alternatively, use base64.

Comment: Looks like you're both right, the escape works fine https://jsfiddle.net/zamyn1fu/